# Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (String)

Tags: delphi-7, ado

При добавлении данных в БД возникает ошибка:

> Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (String)

Как исправить эту ошибку?

```
var
  fio:string;
  pol:string;
  dr:TDateTime;
  doc_ser:string;
  doc_nom:string;
  ss_nom:string;
  nom_kart:string;
  podr:integer;
  dolgn:integer;
  CatPers:string;
  Person_ID:string;
  tip_doz:integer;
  nom_doz:string;
begin
  Form25.ADOQuery1.Post;
  fio := Edit1.Text;
  pol := ComboBox1.Items;
  dr := DateTimePicker1.Date;
  doc_ser := Edit4.Text;
  doc_nom := Edit5.Text;
  ss_nom := Edit6.Text;
  nom_kart := Edit7.Text;
  Person_ID := Edit8.Text;
  podr := DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue;
  dolgn := DBLookupComboBox3.KeyValue;
  CatPers := DBLookupComboBox4.KeyValue;
  tip_doz := DBLookupComboBox2.KeyValue;
  nom_doz := Edit9.Text;

  form25.ADOQuery1.Close;
  form25.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  form25.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Insert Into PersonKart(Person_ID, fio,  doc_ser,  doc_nom, ss_nom, nom_kart)');
  form25.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Values ("'+Edit8.Text+'", "'+Edit1.Text+'",   "'+Edit4.Text+'", "'+Edit5.Text+'", "'+Edit6.Text+'", "'+Edit7.Text+'")');
  form25.ADOQuery1.Active := True;
  form25.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  Form25.ADOQuery1.Refresh;
  form25.ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
  Form25.ADOQuery1.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: **Убирайте из кода все лишнее.** Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код** для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: С кодом уже более-менее разобралась.
Есть еще ошибки
Если не устраню, напишу